# SQLAlchemy Multi table join in relationship field at model class

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Let's assume situation in which there are 3 tables or may I say model classes:

- User
- School
- Subject

In such relation:
`User` ManyToMany `School` ManyToMany `Subject`.
These many to many relationships are defined in association tables like so:

```
school_user = db.Table('school_user ',
                     db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id')),
                     db.Column(school_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('schools.id')))


subject_school = db.Table('subject_school ',
                           db.Column('school_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('schools.id')),
                           db.Column('subject_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('subjects.id')))

class User(db.Model):
    schools= db.relationship('School', secondary=school_user , backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))

class Subject(db.Model):
    schools= db.relationship('School',
                              secondary=subject_school,
                              backref=db.backref('subjects',
                                                 lazy='dynamic'))
```

I would like to query all `Subjects` that belongs to `Schools` that `User` attends to.

I can easily achieve it via:

```
class User:
    @property
    def subjects(self):
        return (Subject
                .query
                .join(School, Subject.schools)
                .join(User, School.users)
                .filter(User.id == self.id)
                .all())
```

My question: Is it achievable via SQLAlchemy relationship field using `primaryjoin` and `secondaryjoin`? Something like (not working, for demo purpose):

```
class User:
    subjects = db.relationship('Subject', 
                               secondary=subject_school, 
                               secondaryjoin='School.id==subject_school.c.school_id', 
                               primaryjoin='Subject.id==subject_school.c.subject_id')
```

Obviously, User join is missing in example above, because I don't know how to apply it correctly.